# Why does Felix Leiter introduce himself to Bond, who should already know him?

Tags: james-bond, casino-royale

In [*Casino Royale (2006)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381061/), Felix Leiter introduces himself to Bond when he goes after Le Chiffre. However, in the previous Bond movies such as [*The Living Daylights (1987)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093428/), Bond already met Felix Leiter. So, the question is, Why does Felix Leiter introduce himself to Bond when they have already met?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 2006 film "Casino Royale" marks a reboot of the series and not a continuation of the previous films

> **From [Wikipedia article for Casino Royale (2006 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(2006_film)):**
>
> Casino Royale reboots the series, establishing a new timeline and
> narrative framework not meant to precede or succeed any previous Bond
> film

In the context of Bond chronology "Casino Royale" occurs before "The Living Daylights. The novel "Casino Royale" marks the first of the James Bond series having been published 13 April 1953 while "The Living Daylights" is based on a short story from the book ["Octopussy and The Living Daylights"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_James_Bond_novels_and_short_stories#1968.E2.80.9379) which was published 23 June 1966.

Comment: It's also possible that "Felix Leiter" is an assumed/code name and passed between agents as and when the previous occupant of the name is retired.

This could also lead to the film being in the same timeline, just earlier than 'The Living Daylights'. Whilst that's not the intention of the Daniel Craig 'Bond' films, it's another possible explanation for those who insist in having them all in the same chronology.

Comment: @gabe that's the general theory for Bond too, it's an alias, not his real name.

Comment: @cde With Bond it's a bit harder to see as we know his back story, or most of it.  Sure they could all have had a similar start to their vocation, but if they are looking for code names and similar, then Bond probably wouldn't have held such emotional significance to something like Skyfall as the background would be different on a per-Bond basis

Comment: @gabe3886 the character of Felix Leiter has been in James Bond's movies since start (though a few exceptions are there) and since Casino Royale reboots the James Bond series, there was need of introducing the character of Felix Leiter.